# Referring to a variable-named worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am having trouble using a variable worksheet name in other areas of my code.  I would like to hide a worksheet based on the name, which uses the date in a particular cell.  Here is the applicable code.

```
Sub StartMedCount()

Dim actionname As String
actionname = "Action List " & Sheets("MedicationCounts").Range("C2").Value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(actionname).Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False

end sub
```

I have a sheet already named "Action List 11-24-2021" and cell C2 contains 11-24-2021.  I get a Runtime error 9 - subscript out of range.  Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Try changing `.value` to `.text`

Comment: Try: `& Format$(Sheets("MedicationCounts").Range("C2").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this below and it works for me.

```
Sub StartMedCount()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ActioNname As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MedicationCounts")
    ActioNname = "Action List " & ws.Range("C2").Value
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActioNname).Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We found the following fix:

The date in C2 was formatted in `mm-dd-yyyy` format but the true value was `mm/dd/yyyy`.  We changed the format to text and inputted it using hyphens.  Elsewhere in the code when I add that date, I use Format to change it to hyphens before it's entered into the cell.